# How to set dynamic JSON String in Thymeleaf

Tags: json, thymeleaf, i18next

I use Thymeleaf in frontend pages, and for some reason I have to deal with i18n by i18next.js instead of spring framework.

According to the [i18next-jquery introduction - using options in translation function](https://github.com/i18next/jquery-i18next#using-options-in-translation-function), I write like this:

```
<span data-i18n="myKey" data-i18n-options='{ "WHERE": "TW" }'></span>
```

And there is my language resource:

```
{ "myKey" : "User is from {{WHERE}}."  }
```

And html is parsed and showed like this perfectly:

```
<span data-i18n="myKey" data-i18n-options='{ "WHERE": "TW" }'> User is from TW. </span>
```

But when I set {{WHERE}} dynamically by Thymeleaf attributes, it just can't be parsed anything.

I tried 

 `th:attrappend="data-i18n-options='{WHERE: '+ ${country} +'}'"` 
also

 `th:data-i18n-options="'{WHERE: '+ ${country} +'}'"`, 

somehow it just end up like this:

```
<span data-i18n="myKey" data-i18n-options="{WHERE: TW}">User is from  .</span>
```

So I wonder that is there any idea to parse json string in Thymeleaf attribute ?

**Update:**
I want to share my **solution**,and I hope it will save someone's time :)

`th:attrappend='data-i18n-options=|{ "WHERE":"${country}"}|'`

or
 `th:data-i18n-options='|{ "WHERE":"${country}"}|'`

Comment: Isn't the problem that you don't have the double quotes in the dynamic version? So maybe try: `th:attrappend="data-i18n-options='{\"WHERE\": \"'+ ${country} +'\"}'"` ?

Comment: @WimDeblauwe  I tried your way but shows "TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing ". Although it's not work, I want to thank your reply and that inspire me to find a solution.

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer, I will upvote it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try these two:

`th:attrappend='data-i18n-options=|{ "WHERE":"${country}"}|'`
or

`th:data-i18n-options='|{ "WHERE":"${country}"}|'`